# Optional argument "#1" being evaluated before substitution in d\formatdate

Tags: macros, environments, datetime

I ran into a problem with the datetime package's `\formatdate{}{}{}` function when I was trying to create a custom environment which is like a journal entry with a date from optional arguments. I noticed it also happens with a new command. In particular, it throws arguments when I try the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newcommand{worddate}[3]{\formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \formatdate{7}{12}{2023}
  \worddate{2023}{12}{7}
\end{document}
```

or with the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newenvironment{datedentry}[3][]{
    \formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1}}
}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{datedentry}{2023}{12}{7}
  test
  \end{datedentry}
\end{document}
```

In either case, it seems that the \formatdate function is immediately evaluating `#1`, etc. instead of the substituted values. Is there a way around this behaviour? I am not sure if it is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a missing begin document error as

```
\newcommand{worddate}[3]{\formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1}}
```

should be

```
\newcommand{\worddate}[3]{\formatdate{#3}{#2}{#1}}
```

with a `\`

If the backslash is added, the output is as expected

[image]

---

The error in the second block is unrelated.

You have

```
\newenvironment{datedentry}[3][]{
```

so defining one optional and 2 mandatory arguments to be used as

```
\begin{datedentry}[1]{2}{3}
```

But you want three mandatory arguments so use

```
\newenvironment{datedentry}[3]{
```

without the `[]`

Comment: Oh my, I feel so silly. Thanks so much!